# Apache Reverse Proxy Config

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy

So ive got a Debian 9 box running running Apache 2.4.25

I would like Apache to also serve web content from another server (http://192.168.1.100:8088) on the network; I have setup mod_proxy to do this but struggling to get things to work.

This config seems like it is nearly working as I get some error content from the correct server, seems like there is a url issue with the app1 endpoint being appended to the url perhaps? this endpoint does not actually exist anywhere and is just used to catch requests.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    <proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </proxy>
    ProxyPass /app1 http://192.168.1.100:8088/
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost/
</virtualHost>
```

If I try to proxy all requests like so it works fine but clearly I cannot access any resources on localhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    <proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.100:8088/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
</virtualHost>
```

I think that perhaps I need to perform some sort of ReWrite? im not particularly experienced using Apache mod_proxy.

:-(

Comment: A few things:  1) You should match the terminating slash (i.e., in your example, it should be "/app1/" vice "/app1", if you're using "http://192.168.1.100:8088/".  2) The URL for ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse should match.  3) You haven't mentioned what is being proxied.  Some web services require additional directives in your Apache proxy.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you have at least two apparent problems:

1. "Terminating" slashes in each individual `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` statement need to match.
2. `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` need to refer to the same host.

So, in your first example:

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://192.168.1.100:8088/
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost/
```

Should be:

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://192.168.1.100:8088
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://192.168.1.100:8088
```

Or:

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost
```

For your second example, `/` is considered a "terminating" slash for the purposes mentioned here. So:

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.100:8088/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
```

Simply needs to have the hosts matched:

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.100:8088/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.100:8088/
```

Or:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
```

**Notes**

- It's probably worth mentioning that the way Apache handles the URLs it proxies, using `/` may get better results than `/app1` depending on how the receiving application constructs its own URLs.
- You may need to proxy multiple URLs depending on how the receiving application works.
- You may wish to enable `mod_proxy_html` and `mod_proxy_http` on top of `mod_proxy` if they aren't already enabled for some reason.